# overheating of GPU(Nvidia gefore 920m) and degraded battery life

Tags: nvidia, battery, bumblebee, overheating

i have dell inspiron-5558(i5-5200;8GB DRR3 RAM;4GB Nvidia-Geforce 920M as well intel HD graphics) and i am using Ubuntu 16.04LT

in my windows i had a battery life of around 4-5 hours reading pdf but now my battery after being fully charged works for about 100minutes. even my Laptop  is heating a lot i think it is because of GPU.

i have researched alot installed latest nvidia drivers. installed bumblebee and power management tools but still it is consuming alot of battery on standby

[versions of nvidia drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLVAq.png) (i have tried all of them)

even the command optirun is not working 
[error in running optirun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PaSc.png)

i am not even sure nvidia is working or not or if its constantly on.
regarding temperature i dont think any ScreenShot will work but it is pretty hot.

i am not very good with linux. so please tell the commands along with the content of answers. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you but this is a known issue with Linux on Laptops, here is a couple of articles I think may help some.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/improve-battery-life-linux

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/power-batterylife.html

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with nvidia-361 drivers on Geforce GT720M card.
In my case temperatures on gpu were about 80C peak and cpu 91C peak, measured with psensor.

I have downgraded drivers to nvidia-340 through Additional drivers, but somehow I don't see them in your Additional drivers - did you add ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa repository (http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html) ?

Now I have max 71C for gpu and max 75C for cpu.